# cql solr fetching diversity result

Tags: solr, cassandra, lucene

I'm curious if possible to get some kind of diversity in fetching the data from cassandra using solr lucene indexing? For example, get only one product per category for one page?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the CQL integration, but on the Solr side this would be known as either [Result Grouping](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/result-grouping.html) or the more recent [Collapse and Expand feature](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/collapse-and-expand-results.html).

Comment: thank you for quick answer. but as I know cql doesn't support grouping the way it's implemented in pure solr.